# Minimum value of $ f(x,y,z)=\left(x+\frac{1}{y}\right)^2+\left(y+\frac{1}{z}\right)^2+\left(z+\frac{1}{x}\right)^2. $

Tags: inequality, optimization, maxima-minima, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

> If $x>0$, $y>0$, $z>0$ and $x+y+z=6$ then find the minimum value of 
>   $$
> f(x,y,z)=\left(x+\frac{1}{y}\right)^2+\left(y+\frac{1}{z}\right)^2+\left(z+\frac{1}{x}\right)^2.
> $$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any ideas? What are your attempts? Where did you stuck? Please show some efforts such that we see your level.

Comment: Welcome to the site ! How to you expect to get any help if we do not know what you already tried.

Comment: I'm new here on stackexchange.I don't know how to type maths here (which you probably know). Sorry for not being supportive to you guys.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference  mathjax references.

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh Thanks buddy

Comment: Essentially the same question as [Minimum value of $\left(a+\frac{1}{b}\right)^2+\left(b+\frac{1}{c}\right)^2+\left(c+\frac{1}{a}\right)^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2287621/minimum-value-of-lefta-frac1b-right2-leftb-frac1c-right2-lef) – the only difference is that here the given sum is $6$ and not $12$. Did you have a look at the "Related" questions?

Comment: @MartinR thanks for suggestion, I'm new here, I didn't notice that.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks for suggestions buddy!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By C-S
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(x+\frac{1}{y}\right)^2=\frac{1}{3}\cdot(1+1+1)\sum_{cyc}\left(x+\frac{1}{y}\right)^2\geq\frac{1}{3}\left(\sum_{cyc}\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)^2\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{1}{3}\left(6+\frac{9}{6}\right)^2=\frac{75}{4}.$$
The equality occurs for $x=y=z=2$, which says that $\frac{75}{4}$ is an answer.

C-S it's the following.
$$(a_1^2+a_2^2+...+a_n^2)(b_1^2+b_2^2+...+b_n^2)^2\geq(a_1b_1+a_2b_2+...+a_nb_n)^2.$$
In our case
$(1^2+1^2+1^2)\left(\left(x+\frac{1}{y}\right)^2+\left(y+\frac{1}{z}\right)^2+\left(z+\frac{1}{x}\right)^2\right)\geq\left(x+\frac{1}{y}+y+\frac{1}{z}+z+\frac{1}{x}\right)^2$ and
$$\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}=\frac{1}{6}(x+y+z)\left(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}\right)\geq\frac{(1+1+1)^2}{6}=\frac{9}{6}$$

Comment: How did you apply C-S inequality?

Comment: Now i got it.Thanks Michael.

Comment: @Arpit Yadav You are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Michael Rozenberg's solution is great, and I think this is the way to go. I just want to point out that it is possible to solve this problem just by observing that there is a great deal of symmetry. What we know is that the available resources must add up to $6$, and since the coefficients in front of each variable are $1$, we do not "penalize" any variable more than the others. The same goes with the cost function (where each variable is presented in the same way as the others). Since this is the case we can actually transform this problem into an one variable problem, thus $v=x=y=z$. We can now write the optimization problem as
$$
\underset{v>0}{\text{minimize}}\quad 3(v+1/v)^2\\
\text{subject to}\quad v=2 
$$
From this, we can directly conclude that the only point that is acceptable is $v=2$, yielding a cost of $75/4$. This is both the maximum and the minimum point (since it is the only point).