# Find the minimum value of $(a+\frac{1}{b})^2 + (b+\frac{1}{c})^2 + (c+\frac{1}{a})^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math

**Full statement:** If $a, b, c > 0$ and $a+b+c = 6$, Find the minimum value of $(a+\frac{1}{b})^2 + (b+\frac{1}{c})^2 + (c+\frac{1}{a})^2$

I've found this problem online, to me it seems like a typical olympiad inequality problem. However, I wasn't not able to solve it, at least correctly. I tried using the AM-GM inequality directly, but I think I did a mistake in that approach or the approach itself is incorrect since I got the minimum to be 432, which is obviously false and easily proved so by a direct calculation.

Comment: Sure it's the same question, now I've got the answer. However, I don't want my question closed now, I'd like to know if a solution without using C-S inequality exists.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2287621/minimum-value-of-lefta-frac1b-right2-leftb-frac1c-right2-lef presents solutions with Jensen's and QM-AM.

Answer (score 0):

Comment:

I give this comment for discussion. due to solutions previously given in the links in comment the answer is:

$3S=\frac{27^2}4$ ⇒ $s=15.187$

But I found the minimum as $18.75$. I am not sure my solution is correct; here it is:

We use following inequality:

$$bc(b+c)+ac(a+c)+ab(a+b) ≥ 6abc$$

Dividing both sides by $abc $we get:

$$\big(\frac{b}a+\frac{c}a\big)+\big(\frac{c}b+\frac{a}b\big)+\big(\frac{a}c+\frac{b}c\big)≥ 6$$

$$(\frac{6}a-1)+(\frac{6}b-1)+(\frac{6}c-1)≥6$$

$$\frac{6}a+\frac{6}b+\frac{6}c≥9$$

$$\frac{2}a+\frac{2}b+\frac{2}c≥3$$

Therefore the minimum is when $a=b=c=2$ ; plugging this in we get:

$$S=3\times(2+\frac{1}2)^2=\frac{75}4=18.75$$